# Are invertible linear operators of bounded linear operators also bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I have this definition in my book:

> **Definition:** 
>   Let X,Y be normed linear spaces. An operator $T \in B(X,Y)$ is said to be invertible if there exists $S \in B(Y,X)$ such
>   that $ST=I_X, TS=I_Y$, in which case S is the inverse of T and is
>   denoeted $T^{-1}$.

B is the set of bounded linear operators from the respective space to the other.

One problem with this definition is that it assumes the existence of S in $B(X,Y)$. I was thinking is it enough to assume the existence of S in the set of all operators from Y to X, and then show that if $ST=I_x, TS=I_Y$ it is in $B(X,Y)$? I was able to show that if T is linear, then S is also linear, but I am not able to show that S is bounded, is it nececarrily bounded or must we assume that it is bounded(and hence in $B(Y,X$))?

That is, if $\|T(x)\|\le \|T\|\|x\|, T(ax_1+bx_2)=aT(x_1)+bT(x_2)$. I can then show that $S(ay_1+by_2)=aS(y1)+bS(Y_2)$, but can I show that there exist an M such that:

$\|S(y)\|\le M\|y|, \forall y \in Y$?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem

Answer (score 2):

If an inverse of any kind exist, $T$ is a bijection. As a [consequence of the open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem), a bijective operator is *bounded from below*, meaning that there is $c>0$ such that $\|Tx\|\ge c\|x\|$ for all $x$. This and the property $TS=I$ imply that $S$ is bounded.